# How to do validation for a mandatory field without using Binding Path

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The problem i have now is that, 
For each textBox i have currently, i have to specify a Binding path in order to validate whether the textBox is empty or not. 
However, if it so happens that i have a hundred textBox, i cant possibly create a get and set method for all 100 textBox individually. So is there any better way to do the current validation that i have now?

Below is the codes that i currently have,

In XAML

```
 <Grid.BindingGroup>
            <BindingGroup Name="RequiredFields">
                <BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
                    <local:MandatoryFieldRule ValidationStep ="CommittedValue"/>
                </BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
            </BindingGroup>
        </Grid.BindingGroup>
            <TextBox x:Name="ds_instruct" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30"
               Margin="286,186,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"    
               Width="275" FontSize="11" GotFocus="textBox_Expand"                                                     
               LostFocus="textBox_Expand" Tag="Default Special Instruction" 
               SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" 
               Text="{Binding  Path=Text, BindingGroupName=RequiredFields,ValidatesOnDataErrors=true}"/>
```

In validation file:

```
public String Text { get; set; }
public String Text1 { get; set; }

 #region IDataErrorInfo Members
   public string Error
    {
        get {throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get 
        {
            string result = null;
            if (columnName == "Text")
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
                {result = "Mandatory field required"; }
            }
            if (columnName == "Text1")
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text1))
                { result = "Mandatory field required"; }
            }
            return result;

        }

    }

    #endregion
```

So my question is, how to validate a mandatory field for multiple textBoxes without specifying a one to one binding(TextBox to a getter and setter method)?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: How are you creating the TextBoxs (100 nos) in runtime? Or the above xaml is a user control that you reuse?

Comment: hi Jacob, in a way, what i meant is that for Binding Path, is there anyway to get the value from text without specifying a get and set method?

Comment: As far as binding is concern, every element in the UI-TextBox should be binded to one Property, it could be the same or a different property. Is it ok, to walk through the controls loaded? but here again you might need to specify the validation for every control.

Comment: You could try this `Binding Validation`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms753962.aspx. This would help you to write custom validators. In runtime, whenever you create a new TextBox hook/bind its validator to this custom validator you have created.

Comment: hi jacob, interesting idea, but i gave in and specified a property for each of the element, creating a entity model to store it in. This is as i would have to do data validation on each of the user control field. Thanks for your suggestion though, i will try it out someday

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use `Reflection` to check the values of the string

```
public string this[string columnName]
{
    get 
    {
        string result = null;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.GetType().GetProperty(columnName).GetValue(this) as string))
        {
            result = "Mandatory field required";
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```